# error: package com.sun.tools.javac.util does not exist

Tags: java, playframework, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to run my play 2.0.1 application on Ubuntu 11.10 and when I visit `domain.com:9000` I get this error in terminal:

```
info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 6 Java sources to /var/www/clients/client3/web10/sc2lounge/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[error] /var/www/clients/client3/web10/sc2lounge/app/models/Cron.java:29: error: package com.sun.tools.javac.util does not exist
[error] import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;
[error]                                ^
[error] 1 error
[error] {file:/var/www/clients/client3/web10/sc2lounge/}sc2lounge/compile:compile: javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application - 

! Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error [error: package com.sun.tools.javac.util does not exist]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:221) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
```

I have `JAVA_HOME` set like this in my `.bashrc` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java  #Which is a symbolic link to java-7-openjdk-common
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

the output of `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

and the output of `javac -version` is:

```
javac 1.7.0_147
```

My question is, why `com.sun.tools.javac.util.List` isn't included in the classpath?

Comment: Interestingly, I had this error happen when I typed Todo without comments and IntelliJ auto-imported `com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Todo`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This class is found in `tools.jar`, which is not part of the JRE.

Comment: So how would I include this in a build path on ubuntu?

Comment: You'll need to include tools.jar in the CLASSPATH setting

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem when I try to build kotlin/jvm with gradle,
I want to post this to others new to jvm,  since jdk-9, there is no `tools.jar`. setting a `classpath` is good to go.

```
JAVA_HOME= path_to_jdk

JRE_HOME= path_to_jre

PATH= ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin

CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JRE_HOME%\lib
```