# package com.sun.tools.javac.code is not visible in JDK17

Tags: java, package, java-17

I tried to access the package com.sun.tools.javac.code in JDK17. Someone said can add the VM args as below:

```
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Werror</arg>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
```

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Werror</arg>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, I still got a compiler error:
`error: package com.sun.tools.javac.code is not visible`

How can I access the com.sun.tools.javac.code in jdk17?
I must access this API and don't want use other ways.

Comment: Have you tried with add-opens for that package name as well?

Comment: @DuncG tried but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the *--add-exports* switch.
Specifically, *"--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED"*.

*[Migrating From JDK 8 to Later JDK Releases](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-2F61F3A9-0979-46A4-8B49-325BA0EE8B66)*.

If that does not work, try referring to the following question.
*[StackOverflow – error: package com.sun.tools.javac.util does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667187/error-package-com-sun-tools-javac-util-does-not-exist)*.

Comment: it still not work

Comment: After I clicked maven install, it shows "error: package com.sun.tools.javac.code is not visible"

Comment: @MichaelTsai do you expect us to write a new answer for every package you are using?

Comment: @Holger no, I already added all using package but it still show using packages is not visible.

Comment: What this answer is telling you, is that you are using `--add-opens` but not `--add-exports`. Regardless of which package.

Comment: @MichaelTsai, interesting, as I thought that would work.  Try the following question and answer, _https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667187/error-package-com-sun-tools-javac-util-does-not-exist_.

Comment: @Holger I actually used --add-exports

Comment: @Reilas I've found the reason. I should not use <fork>true</fork>. After I removed this, everything works. Thanks